# Protractor Process exited with error code 100

Tags: protractor, webdriver, errno

I'm trying to setup protractor on different computer. It is using the same files with my other computer (cannot be used because hdisc corrupted).

It run fine on my other computer but I am getting error "Process exited with error code 100" when I tried to run protractor on this one.

I've tried to delete the node modules, clean cache and perform npm install again to install the dependencies. It helps my earlier issue (cannot run webdriver) but is now causing me this one.

```
[14:44:09] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[14:44:09] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[14:44:11] E/launcher - Error: Error: Server terminated early with status 1
    at earlyTermination.catch.e (C:\Users\PMO\Documents\DG\Jasmine\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\remote\index.js:252:52)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[14:44:11] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 100
npm ERR! ProtractorTutorial@ protractor: `protractor conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 100
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the protractor@ protractor script.
```

My current chrome version is: 74.0.3729.131 
Webdriver version: chromedriver_74.0.3729.6.exe
OS: Windows 10.

Please advise me on how to fix this issue. Or is there any specific version of chrome and webdriver that can work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `directConnect=true` in your `config`. if you are already using that, The problem is with the webdriver.

Try running below commands from your project location

```
webdriver-manager clean

node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --standalone --versions.standalone=3.8.0
```

Comment: Hi Madhan, I am using package script and it run from node module, so your first solution did not work for me. However, i tried to perform webdriver-clean and the update and it is working now. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: adding `directConnect: true` to my config did it!

Comment: I had the same error code 100, but changing my java home to 8, uninstalling webdriver and installing again with the version of my chrome have worked

Comment: There are a couple of issues here, one the latest version (at time of writing) is `12.1.6` so hard coding this command to `3.8.0` is a bit short sighted, two, as soon as you reinstall your npm packages your going to have to do this again. It's much better to actually [update the package and then update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57491921/542251)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue yesterday and inspired by [Madhan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56017638/1714013) I worked it out.

I'm learning angularJS thru the [official tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial). I found `protractor` is actually a standalone tool (I'm a newbie in front-end development), which means it can be run separately.

So following the [official setup guide](https://www.protractortest.org/#/), I run

```
protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js
```

and found below feedback:

```
E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 77
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'xxx', ip: 'xxx', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '11.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: 0   chromedriver_77.0.3865.40           0x00000001078b7f09 chromedriver_77.0.3865.40 + 3694345
```

And my chrome version was 76 in the moment.

So after I upgraded chrome to 77, it worked.

Tips:

if use `directConnect=true` in your config still doesn't work, try to run in standalone mode, which can provide you more useful feedback.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was a space after Scenario in the feature file

Wrong  `Scenario :`
Corrected to `Scenario:` and the feature started executing

Cant see this answer above, so this might help someone

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that you need to run your tests *without* sudo!

Sometimes if you get an EACCESS error, you can then change directory permissions so that you can run it without sudo.

Answer (score 0):

My issue here was an outdated version of `webdriver-manager`. [This fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56017638/542251) only partially fixes the issue because it does not update the npm package. To completely fix this you need to ensure your package.json is configured with the correct `webdriver-manager` version (`npm install webdriver-manager@latest --save-dev`). Then you'll need to run:

- `npm install`
- `node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager clean`
- `node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update`

You may also need to run a `npm dedupe` to ensure all items are using the new package

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to run update + start

```
node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --standalone --versions.standalone=3.8.0

node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start --standalone --versions.standalone=3.8.0
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a missing `tsconfig.json` file in my e2e folder. If you don't have one in your e2e folder, simply create one and put this code into it. Then run `ng e2e` again.

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/e2e",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "jasminewd2",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm using:

Angular CLI: 9.0.7

Node: 14.16.0

Chrome: 89.0.4389.82

chromedriver_89.0.4389.23