# Protractor tests Azure Pipelines - using Internet Explorer

Tags: azure-devops, protractor, internet-explorer-11

We have a big set of automated tests using Protractor/Jasmine which work like a dream on Azure Pipelines. However, so far we've only used Chrome as the browser.

Now i have to run the same tests using Internet Explorer (11) but am getting no joy at all!!

Here's a part of my `conf.js` file that deals with the browser:

```
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-beautiful-reporter');
var  {SpecReporter}  = require("jasmine-spec-reporter");
var jasmineReporters = require("jasmine-reporters");

exports.config = {
//seleniumAddress: `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub`,

 framework: "jasmine2",

   specs: ['specs/secureTrading/01_SecureTrading.js',
  'specs/secureTrading/02_ST_Payments.js'

],

getPageTimeout: 40000,
allScriptsTimeout: 60000,


capabilities: { 
'browserName': 'internet explorer', 
'ignoreProtectedModeSettings': true, 
'platform': 'ANY', 
'version': '11', 
args: ['--silent', '--no-sandbox', '--test-type=browser', '--lang=US', '--start-maximized'], //,'--headless', '--disable-gpu' 
prefs: { 
    'download': {
        'prompt_for_download': false, 
        'directory_upgrade': true, 
        'extensions_to_open': '', 
        'default_directory': process.cwd() + '/downloads/'
    }, 
 } 
}, 
   localSeleniumStandaloneOpts: { 
jvmArgs: [ 
    '-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/IEDriverServer3.14.0.exe'
] 
}, 
directConnect: false, 

seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/IEDriverServer3.14.0.exe'], 



ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true,



 onPrepare: function() {
```

Having looked at other postings, I've tried removing // from `seleniumAddress:`http://localhost:4444/wd/hub,` still errors, Changing DirectConnect makes no difference.

With the settings as above, this is the error message.

[image]

Any advice please?

Thanks

**Additional Logs as per comment below.**

Local:
[image]

Comment: Could you set `System.debug=true` and update with the completed log? This error message are too wide. In addition, since you are using Command Line task, what about run this test from local? As normal, if it succeed locally, it will not facing error in Azure Devops.

Comment: Hi @MerlinLiang-MSFT The test is now no longer running locally (tried several machines.Please see in main body for logs.

Comment: You could give a try with `directConnect: true`. For more information, you could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56000297/protractor-process-exited-with-error-code-100). If it still doesn't work, you could try to enable or disable all the protected mode on all 4 zones in IE. Make sure the statuses are the same on all zones. You could check [this article](https://qavalidation.com/2017/11/run-protractor-test-ie-internet-explorer.html/) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456099/protractor-test-in-ie) for the detailed steps.