# Protractor : MicrosoftEdge Driver : Error: Error: Server terminated early with status 1

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor, driver, microsoft-edge

**I have followed the below but still not able to run Microsoft edge**

In windows to download the MicrosoftEdge Webdriver for the HTML version >= 18 then follow the below steps
Open Command Prompt, issue the following command and wait until operation gets completed

```
DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0
```

Open the File Explorer and navigate to C:\Windows\WinSxS and search for MicrosoftWebDriver and it will display two results, copy the webdriver from the amd64_microsoft-webdriver-server-components10.0.18362.1_none and paste it in

```
/c/Users/Administrator/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-`manager/selenium
```

(Note: Using git bash, it's easy to copy the Webdriver)

In the config file of Edge browser, make the following changes

```
seleniumArgs:['-Dwebdriver.edge.driver=C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\webdriver-manager\\selenium\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe'],

    capabilities: {
    
        'browserName': 'MicrosoftEdge',
        'maxInstances': 1,
        'platformName': 'windows',
        'nativeEvents': false,
         shardTestFiles: true,
      },
```

Open the command prompt, and navigate to project repo and issue the following command to start the edge session

```
webdriver-manager start --edge "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe"`
```

**Getting an error as :**

```
[23:38:22] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[23:38:22] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[23:38:22] E/launcher - Error: Error: Server terminated early with status 1
    at C:\Collabera\Web Automation\Spades3\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\remote\index.js:252:52
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
[23:38:22] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 100
npm ERR! spades3@1.0.0 test: `protractor JSFiles/configuration.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 100
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the spades3@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

**Thanks**

**Aakash Paliwal**

Comment: hi Paliwal, you can try following this link **[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56000297/protractor-process-exited-with-error-code-100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56000297/protractor-process-exited-with-error-code-100)**

Comment: Can you please inform us, which version of the Edge browser you are using for making this test? Are you able to run the web driver if you double click the web driver? If yes, then the issue may be related to something else. If possible then try to share the steps how did you configure the protector? for testing purposes, try to use the latest version of the nodeJS.

Comment: Hi  AquariusPotter,
Edge does not work on direct connect.

Comment: Hi Deepak,
--Edge Version:87.0.664.66
Are you able to run the web driver if you double click the web driver?
--Yes
 for testing purposes, try to use the latest version of the nodeJS. – Deepak-MSFT 
I am using the latest version of nodeJS

Comment: As you said in the original post, you are running the `DISM.exe` command to install the web driver but it will install the web driver for Edge legacy browser. We can see that you are using the Edge Chromium browser. So it looks like you are not using the correct web driver. I suggest you visit [this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) and download the correct web driver for your Edge Chromium browser according to the version of the Edge browser. Then again make a test.

Comment: Sure will try and let you know
Thanks Deepak